# How to format dates when writing excel files with spout

Tags: php, date-formatting

I need to generate some pretty large excel files, and I was thinking of switching from PHPExcel to spout, since it seems to be much more efficient. I have been able to find every feature I needed, except one: how to format a cell as date. It seems to think that by default everything is a string. For numbers I have found that using `intval()` or `floatval()` forces it to consider the value a number, but is there anything similar for dates?

The only workaround I have found so far is to convert the date to a number using  `(strtotime($datestr)/86400)+25569.4167` , but then you have to manually format the column as a date after exporting the file, but the users will not accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I have found this commit on github https://github.com/box/spout/pull/209 where they add the option to format dates and, amongst other things, to format cells individually. I know this is not an official release, and so it is "use at your own risk", but for me it was just what I needed, so I thought to add the link just in case someone else is in the same situation. Warning, though, it does break setting the background color for both a cell and a row, but in my case that wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to format a cell as a date for now. You can always pass a date string (like "03/03/2017"); Excel is usually pretty good at recognizing that this is a date.

Your workaround indeed requires a manual step to configure the column as a date, so I would not recommend doing this.